# Trying to Upload Image through Joomla Administrator Component Field, but not happening

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to upload image through Joomla Administrator Component

In administrator\components\com_toys\models\forms\variant.xml i have defined

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
<field name="id" type="text" readonly="true" class="readonly" default="0" description="JGLOBAL_FIELD_ID_DESC"/>
<field name="v_prod_id" type="sql" label="Select Brand"/>   
<field name="v_name" type="text" label="Select Model"/>
<field name="v_descr" type="editor" buttons="true" filter="safehtml" label="Toy Details"/>
<field name="v_price" type="text" label="Price"/>   
<field name="v_small_img" type="file" label="Select Image"/>

<field name="state" type="list" label="JSTATUS" description="JFIELD_PUBLISHED_DESC" class="inputbox" size="1" default="0">
  <option value="1">JPUBLISHED</option>
  <option value="0">JUNPUBLISHED</option>
  <option value="2">JARCHIVED</option>
  <option value="-2">JTRASHED</option>
</field>
```

In the controller administrator\components\com_toys\controllers\variant.php im trying to retrieve that file like below

But the file is neither uploaded and nor saved in directory - /images/uploads/variants/ and also not saved in database

Can someone help pls what is wrong, why is the file not getting saved

**Update**
It was easy as i was not aware that Joomla has inbuilt solution by declaring field type " />

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong name of form

```
$files = $jinput->files->get('jform');
```

it is not jform it is `v_small_img`

So use this

```
    $input = new JInput;

    $file = $input->get('v_small_img', '', 'post');
```

Also dont use $_FILES again when you have $file. Use this instead

`$file['tmp_name'];` `JFile::makeSafe($file['name']);`

Wherever you have used $_FILES.

UPDATED with full code changes

```
public function save($key = null, $urlVar = null)
{
    $input = new JInput;

    $file = $input->get('v_small_img', '', 'post');
    //$file = $files['image'];

    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    //$post   = JRequest::get( 'post' );
    $FILE_PATH= JPATH_BASE ."/images/uploads/variants/";
    //$StrFiles="";

    if((file_exists($file['tmp_name']))){
        if($file['name']!=""){
            $dt = time()."s";
            if(!JFile::upload($file['tmp_name'],$FILE_PATH.JFile::makeSafe($dt."_".$file['name']))){
                return JError::raiseWarning( 500, "Unable To upload File ".$file['name']);
            }else{
               // $StrFiles .=JFile::makeSafe($dt."_".$file['name']);
            }
        } else {
        return JError::raiseWarning( 500, "File name cannot be empty.");
    }
    }
    /*if($StrFiles){
        $post['v_small_img']= $StrFiles;
    }*/
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, thanks - i changed, but it makes no help as the image when uploaded is not saved in db, or the image folder path

Comment: Dont use $_POST as you can use JInput. Where from you got his `$_POST['old_v_small_img']`. is this info passed through url. Also where is this function used `saveOrderAjax()`?

Comment: Hi  - the old_v_small_img seems incorrect - hence removed. changing $_FILES with the code given leads to syntax error, i might be doing something wrong may be of colon. is it possible to. advise on the edit code as placed in

Comment: @Ruchika I have updated your entire code. Hope you can clean the unnecessary codes. If any error you faced let me know.

Comment: Hello, somehow not saving yet :(

Comment: on enabling maximum error - showing undefined v_small_img

Comment: @Ruchika Can you paste your modified code here? Also give all related upload codes of model and controller separately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118978/discussion-between-amit-ray-and-ruchika).

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
It was easy as i was not aware that Joomla has inbuilt solution by declaring field
type

```
<field name="v_small_img" type="media" directory="<upload path>" />
```

By choosing that image can be easily loaded in the desired directory
In meanwhile - thanks Amit ray for taking an attempt